# Specific date time pattern in Arabic

Tags: android, datetime

I have a web service that returns the date (as a string) in this form 2016-10-4. How can I transform it to Tuesday, September 2016 or الثلاثاء, تشرين أو  2016?

This is what I'm using:

```
String date = news.get(position).getPublishDate().substring(0,news.get(pos‌​ition).getPublishDat‌​e().indexOf("T"));
SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMMM-dddd");     
holder.date.setText(sdf.format(date))
```

and it gives me

> Bad class: class java.lang.string

Comment: Use `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: yeah how to put the mm and dd (The date is returned as a string)

Comment: What had you tried so far? Similar questions were asked bazillion times here on SO... *but It's urgent* then stop wasting time on asking questions here and learn how to use internet search and read docs

Comment: String date = news.get(position).getPublishDate().substring(0,news.get(position).getPublishDate().indexOf("T"));
        SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMMM-dddd");
        holder.date.setText(sdf.format(date));

Comment: but it's giving me an error (Bad class: class java.lang.string)

Comment: I can't even flag this as duplicate because I can't chose between all duplicates..

Comment: @eshteghelcompany you are setting a string with a date... or better, you are formatting a string to a string..

Comment: You are passing a string where it wants a date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this one

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-d");
Date date = sdf.parse("2016-10-4");
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM yyyy");
String format = sdf.format(date);
System.out.print("Result: " + format);
```

Will be printed:

> Result: Tuesday, October 2016

Comment: it converts the date in english, but it doesn't convert for arabic date

Comment: I don't see anything about arabic language in question. Sorry, but I'm not familiar with Arabic

Answer (score 0):

Use this

`String myFormat = "EEE, MMM d, ''yy";
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);`

Output will be like `Wed, Jul 4, '16`

For further assistance check the link [Simple Date Format in android](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to convert your date to required date but before use this method change your string date to Date format

```
    private static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM yyyy");
public static SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    public static String changeDateFormat(Date date) {
            try {
                String newDate = sdf.format(date);
                return newDate;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

use this method to convert string date to Date type

```
public static Date stringIntoDateFormat(String date) {

        try {
            return df.parse(date);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```